# how to display html page from db

Tags: android, database, sqlite

> I try to store the htmlpage in db as string.then i need display that
>   page in webview. here i paste my code pls help me.......
>   How do you store an html page in a sqlite database in android? I tried
>   to convert the html page into bytes array to store in database. Please
>   help me how to store insert that into db and then open that load in
>   webview...

```
public class AndroidOpenDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "html_db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "html_table";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ID = "html_id_column";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_PAGE = "page_column";


    public AndroidOpenDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //"create table if not exists TABLE_NAME ( BaseColumns._ID integer primary key autoincrement, FIRST_COLUMN_NAME text not null, SECOND_COLUMN_NAME integer not null);"
                String sqlQueryToCreateTable = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                                                                        + COLUMN_NAME_PAGE + " HTML STRING, "
                                                                        ;

                // Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.
                db.execSQL(sqlQueryToCreateTable);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2){
            // Upgrade the database
        }       
    }

    }
```

> and this my code to display page.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     WebView browser;
    private static String inp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.w1);




    }


     private void loadTime(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                   browser.loadDataWithBaseURL("x-data://base",inp,"text/html", "UTF-8",null);

        // browser.loadUrl(inp);

    }
    public static String main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:/mo.html");
          inp = new Scanner(fis,"UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    return inp;
     }
    public void insertUndergraduate(){
        AndroidOpenDbHelper androidOpenDbHelperObj = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = androidOpenDbHelperObj.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_PAGE,inp);

    }
```

> pls help me.....

Comment: what errors do you get? nothing? or?

Comment: it wont display html page

Comment: so the page is "blank"?

Comment: the page is not blank.i open it in my browser it display the conent

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this example:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-embed-a-webview-with-the-webkit-engine/

**This looks right:**

```
WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine); 

String data = "<html>"  +  
          "<body><h1>Yay, Mobiletuts+!</h1></body>"  +  
          "</html>";  

engine.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Now, if that works, I would just SELECT the html into the string from a normal textfield in the database.

Please let me know if this works and is the answer.